# Private storage in 2.1?

Tags: android

I need to store files on SD card or other storage. I'd like this storage

- to be private (not very critical)
- to go away on app uninstall
- not to be erased by OS if resources limited

User will take pictures and they will be uploaded to server. I want to be more or less sure that I have those files until they uploaded and then I will delete them on completion.

I thought getExternalFilesDir is what I need but it's only from API 8 and I develop for API 7 (2.1)

What should i use? What is my best option? Also, is there any way to check available space? I need maybe 2-5Mb total..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store it within your apps data folder and you are good.

Comment: How to get reference to that folder? Is it getFilesDir?